# Will Amazon FBA Warehosues work in with the Domestic Backup Warehouse workflow?

Tags: settings, warehouse

Does the FBA Warehouse function the same as a 3PL/In House Warehouse in the context of Domestic Backup Warehouse Fulfillment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - FBA Warehouses will work with the Domestic Backup Warehouse Workflow

**Notes:**

- You will need to have the orderbot sequence setup
- Need to couple it with an MCF Orderbot for the orders to automatically send to amazon. Otherwise they would just be in awaiting MC Fulfillment
- Additional orderbots needed "If OOS", "If partially in stock" etc

[Link to confirmation in slack](https://skubana.slack.com/archives/CEBMGLS1F/p1612905047489100)